# PHP MySQL jQuery/AJAX issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have problem with jQuery.

**This is my jQuery code:**

```
function UpdateRecord(id)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "index.php",
       data: 'id='+id,
       cache: true,
       success: function(data)
       {
         $('#output').html(data);

       }
     });
 }
```

UpdateRecord(id) get data from here :

```
echo"<select>";
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $product)
    {
        $price = $product->price;
     echo"<option value = $product->id onclick=\"UpdateRecord($product->id)\">$product->p_name</option>";
    }
    echo"</select>";
```

This is piece of the HTML and php code where new result should be <`div id="output"></div>` :

```
$i = 0;
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $pricer){
    if ($i==1) break;    
    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo("<div id=\"output\"><p>$pricer->price</p></div>");
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i++;
    }
```

And finally this is the PHP function which return the price :

```
public function update_price($id){

        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT `price` FROM `products` WHERE id=?");

        $stmt->bindValue(1,$id);

        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

         //echo json_encode($row);

         foreach($row as $data){

            echo $data->price;

         }
}
```

I tested my PHP function and it's working properly.

The problem is when I click on my dropdwon list and choose product the whole `table` is repeating aggain in "`Price`" field like this :

**Normal :**

http://i44.tinypic.com/34473mp.jpg

**Problem :**

http://i43.tinypic.com/3449xmw.jpg

*EDIT*

This the `table` :

```
<tbody>

<?php




foreach($category->fetch_category() as $data){

    $id = $data->id;

    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo"<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$data->id\" />";
    echo"<p><strong>".$data->cat_name."</strong></p>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";

    echo"<select>";
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $product)
    {
        $price = $product->price;
    echo"<option value = $product->id onclick=\"UpdateRecord($product->id)\">$product->p_name</option>";
    }
    echo"</select>";

    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";

    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo"<input class=\"input-mini\" type=\"text\" value=\"1\"/>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $pricer){
    if ($i==1) break;    

    echo"<td id=\"$pricer->category_id\">";

    echo"<center>";
    echo("<div id=\"output\"><p>$pricer->price</p></div>");
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i++;
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}

?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Total: </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

Thanks in advance ! I am trying to fix this for whole day...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to reflect the problem you're having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending request to the same page you should check it for the ajax call and work for the desired part of html this is what you got the whole html of your `index.php` i recommend you to pass another parameter in ajax call and on the top of you `index.php` check for the call

```
function UpdateRecord(id)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "index.php",
       data: 'id='+id+'&ajax_call=1',
       cache: true,
       success: function(data)
       {
         $('#output').html(data);

       }
     });
 }
```

`index.php`

```
if($_REQUEST['ajax_call']){
$i = 0;
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $pricer){
    if ($i==1) break;    
    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo("<div id=\"output\"><p>$pricer->price</p></div>");
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i++;
    }
die();

}
```

**EDIT**

For each category you have price div with id `output` therefore the id duplicating try this

```
 foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $product)
    {
        $price = $product->price;
    echo"<option value = $product->id onclick=\"UpdateRecord($product->id,$data->id)\">$product->p_name</option>";
    }
    echo"</select>";

    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";

    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo"<input class=\"input-mini\" type=\"text\" value=\"1\"/>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $pricer){
    if ($i==1) break;    

    echo"<td id=\"$pricer->category_id\">";

    echo"<center>";
    echo("<div id=\"output-$data->id\"><p>$pricer->price</p></div>");
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i++;
    }
```

JS

```
function UpdateRecord(id,cat_id)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "index.php",
       data: 'id='+id,
       cache: true,
       success: function(data)
       {
         $('#output-'+cat_id).html(data);

       }
     });
 }
```

Comment: You could also just use the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` server variable to detect if it is an ajax call, as detailed here: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: Yes i agree hence idea above is to detect ajax call and work around now depends on OP which method to choose

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly echoing the entire `HTML` Page from the URL that receives the `AJAX` request. 
That is the reason it is bringing in a whole new page and fitting it in the place of `$('#output')`. Can you post the Code of the page that is receiving the `AJAX` request?

Comment: Yes that was the problem but now I have another one i wrote about it as comment of Tjofras answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request is going to index.php. So the data that's coming back is the whole index.php page. That's why everything is getting repeated.

I would recommend creating another PHP file that your ajax code is calling and just generate the HTML you want to return in that PHP file.

Comment: Ok with your help i fixed it, but now it changes only the first price field even if i click on another dropdown... Thank you for that aggain !

Comment: @Mind_Blower Check the id attributes of your all prices field they shouldn't be same , id is supposed to be unique thats the in all ajax calls your first price field id updated

Comment: I added the ID of category in <td> also edited my question so you can see the table.